# git resolve conflict condition

Tags: git

How to make sure that before checking in files in git there are no conflicts?

Before committing any files if we do:

```
 git pull origin master
```

then do

```
 git commit
 git push origin master
```

Is this the case that a user will not get any conflict at all in any case? Please let me know.

Comment: As long as there's only one person doing that at a time.

Comment: The standard way you deal with conflicts is to just commit with abandon, then (with your git repo in a clean state) do a pull. *Then* deal with conflicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
git push origin master
```

The git will let you know if there are any conflicts and won't actually push until that is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Pulling can get you conflicts -- typically, if someone pushed modifications on the same files/lines that you have modified locally ; in such a case, there is no magic : you'll have to resolve the conflict by hand : no program can *guess* what to do.

Having conflicts is to be expected when several developpers work on the same piece of code.

Comment: Hey man would love to see English version of your blog (can't understand French :P), you should really add the support of it.

Comment: Hi :-) Well, I don't have enough time to actually write as often as I'd like... I can't imagine how much additional time it would require to write in english too :-(

Comment: @Sarfraz: You are asking the blog question here :) :)